# VSCode Extension - How to refer to workspace settings' configuration in "when" clause of contributes.menus

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my package.json, I define to add a custom item to the editor context menu.

I want the menu item to be displayed based on the boolean value of a specific configuration in the `settings.json`.

I search online but still could not find a way to do that.

```
"editor/context": [
    {
        "command": "abc",
        "group":"test@1",
        "when": "" <--how to refer to configuration specified in settings.json?
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a context variable with:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExtName:isMenuAllowed', someBoolValue);
```

You have to update this variable whenever the settings change and at the activation of the extension. Extension activation event is thus `"*"` (Always)

```
function setIsMenuAllowed() {
    let someBoolValue = true;
    // get value from config
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExtName:isMenuAllowed', someBoolValue);
}

setIsMenuAllowed();
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration(setIsMenuAllowed, null, context.subscriptions);
```

Then you can use the context variable `myExtName:isMenuAllowed` in the when rule:

```
    "when": "myExtName:isMenuAllowed"
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response.  As i am new to creating extension, I need to read through and try understand your code before using it. Will update u again on my result.
Meanwhile, can i query, whether the myExtName:isMenuAllowed an arbitrary word? 
Also, how do I get value from config?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration

Comment: Hi, thanks manage to get it to work finally! Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Bruce you can mark the answer as a solution